# How to unload project in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I can't find any method to unload project in Xamarin!
My solution was very big and some project can't loaded in Xamarin.
So I want to unload it,they are just some Test Project.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could find to do this is to leave the project in the solution but actually remove it from your build configuration.
Right click on your solution > Preferences > Genereal > Build > Configurations and un-check your project.

This way the project can stay on the solution but the compiler will not try to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Projects cannot be unloaded from a Xamarin solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way I "unload" projects from Xamarin is to delete the `.sln` file from disk. This is a poor method but I think it works for your case since this is a test project.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which was about Projects, but it helped me remove a Solution from Xamarin Studio, which was the problem that brought me here.

Comment: one could say I understood the intent behind the question and answered accordingly (;

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Studio **4.2.4** added this functionality.

> Release notes:
>
> - Added new Project Unload command, which can be used to disable a project in a solution. To unload a project, right-click on the project in the solution pad and click on Unload. An unloaded project will remain disabled until it is explicitly loaded using the Reload command.
>
> Source: http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_4.2/xamarin.studio_4.2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "unload," but you can remove a project from a Xamarin Studio project by right mouse clicking on the project in the solution explorer and select "Delete."

You should then be prompted on whether or not you want to "Delete from Disk," "Cancel," or "Remove." If you select "Remove," the project will be removed from your solution, but will still be left on your hard drive.

You can add the project back in at anytime by right mouse clicking on the solution and selecting "Add Project." If you point XS at the .csproj file it'll show back up in your solution.

Comment: I use the VS zh-cn,in my system the command calls "卸载", so I didn't the name in English.When I "卸载" it,the project won't delete,by only didn't compile it,and I can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that going into the terminal and removing the project folder there like so

```
rm -rf /Projects/project_to_destory/
```

And then opening xamarin studios, click on the project you just deleted and it will ask if you want to remove the reference to the project and click yes. The project is now removed

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017 you can easily right click on the project and select **Unload Project** and you reload it by the same way.